# Unable install libpcap on linux

Tags: linux, libpcap

I try to install libpcap 1.4.0.0

But i always get the status:

```
[root@vsqa054 engfix]# rpm -ish libpcap-1.4.0-1.20130826git2dbcaa1.el6.i686.rpm 

warning:
libpcap-1.4.0-1.20130826git2dbcaa1.el6.i686.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1
Signature, key ID c105b9de: NOKEY
########################################### [100%]
         file /usr/share/man/man7/pcap-filter.7.gz from install of libpcap-14:1.4.0-1.20130826git2dbcaa1.el6.i686 conflicts with file
 from package libpcap-14:1.0.0-6.20091201git117cb5.el6.x86_64
         file /usr/share/man/man7/pcap-linktype.7.gz from install of libpcap-14:1.4.0-1.20130826git2dbcaa1.el6.i686 conflicts with file
 from package libpcap-14:1.0.0-6.20091201git117cb5.el6.x86_64
[root@vsqa054 engfix]#
```

Who can explain for me this status? How can i install libpcap-1.4.0?

Comment: This question should be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/. Anyway, it looks like a 64-bit variant of `libpcap` is already installed on your system. If you need the files required for compiling a program using `libpcap`, you have to install a package `libpcap-dev` or `libpcap-devel` instead (if provided in your systems repository).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the older version is conflicting. Have you tried uninstalling the current libpcap?

I am just guessing as I don't even know what libpcap is but the one it's conflicting with is an old version so perhaps if you got rid of it the new one will install.

Citing another post, albeit from 2008, it says to use `-U` when upgrading, not `-i`.

http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/red-hat-fedora-linux/112273-problem-installing-libpcap.html